# Is it possible to change a value of a meta-data column "changed by" and "modify by"?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to change the value of a meta-data column "changed by" and "Modify by". Because it's is read-only.
Is there a way to change it?

Greetings, P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you mean "Changed by"?

We could use **Send An HTTP Request To SharePoint** action to update the "Modified By" with Microsoft Flow.

Simple test for your reference:

[image]

Result:

[image]

More information for your reference:

http://johnliu.net/blog/2019/2/flowninja-hack-78-modifying-modified-by-and-modified-time-with-microsoft-flow

https://anomepani.github.io/posts/how-to-update-created-by-and-modified-by-field-in-sharepoint-list-using-rest-api/